# get the row and column of a Data.Array in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to get the row of a Data.Array in haskell and also get the column of an array in the form of a tuple or list.

I have something like this:

```
 array ((0,0),(2,2)) [((i,j),3*i+j)| i <- [0..2], j <- [0..2]]
```

And I want to get something like:

(0,1,2)

(3,4,5)

or:

(0,3,6)

(1,4,7)

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you want. Can you imagine a hypothetical function that would solve your problem, and then provide some examples of input and output of this function?

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`Data.Array.assocs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.4.0.1/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html#v%3aassocs) function:

```
Prelude> import Data.Array
Prelude Data.Array> let arr = array ((0,0),(2,2)) [((i,j),3*i+j)
                                                  | i <- [0..2], j <- [0..2]]
Prelude Data.Array> assocs arr
[((0,0),0),((0,1),1),((0,2),2),((1,0),3)
,((1,1),4),((1,2),5),((2,0),6),((2,1),7),((2,2),8)]
```

Comment: From there, you can get the individual rows and columns through ordinary list processing (i.e. `map` and `filter`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:
`[arr ! (i, 0) | i <- [0..2]]` or something similar